# Как обратиться к вложенному span и передать его значение в переменную?

Tags: javascript

Нужно обратиться к вложенному тегу `<span>`, чтобы передать значение (в данном случае `2940 руб.`), вот разметка:

```
 <div class="nad_orange zver" style="color:#2E0648;">
    Какой-то текст: <span>2940 руб.</span>
 </div>
```

Если добавить в тег `<span>` `id` (`pri_jsss`) то можно сделать так:

```
let pri2 = document.getElementById('pri_jsss');
var txt2 = pri2.innerHTML;
```

Нужно без добавления `id`, быть может есть какой то способ через родителя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let parent = document.querySelector('.nad_orange');
let children = parent.childNodes;

for (let i of children) {
  if (i.tagName == 'SPAN') {
    console.log(i.textContent);
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="nad_orange zver" style="color:#2E0648;">
             Какой-то текст:  <span>2940 руб.</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.zver > span');
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.textContent);
});
```

```html
<div class="nad_orange zver" style="color:#2E0648;">
    Какой-то текст: <span>2940 руб.</span>
</div>
```

Можно так:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.zver span');
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.textContent);
});
```

```html
<div class="nad_orange zver" style="color:#2E0648;">
    Какой-то текст: <span>2940 руб.</span>
</div>
<div class="nad_orange zver" style="color:#2E0648;">
    Какой-то текст: <span>2940 руб.</span>
</div>
```

Выборка всего текста из всех тегов `<span>`

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('span');
elements.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element.textContent);
});
```

```html
<div class="nad_orange zver" style="color:#2E0648;">
    Какой-то текст: <span>2940 руб.</span>
</div>
<div class="nad_orange zver" style="color:#2E0648;">
    Какой-то текст: <span>2940 руб.</span>
    Какой-то текст1: <span>300 руб.</span>
    Какой-то текст2: <span>Нет денег</span>
</div>
<div>
    Какой-то текст: <span>2940 руб.</span>
</div>
<span>Убежал</span>
```